# How can I return value DB::Select Join with view page in controller?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I try to select two items from 'clients' table :

```
$DF = DemandeFinancement::findOrFail($ndf);
    $arr = array('DF'=>$DF);


$client = DB::table('clients')
        ->join('demande_financements', 'clients.id', '=', 'demande_financements.id')
        ->select('clients.id', 'clients.name')
        ->get();
```

I would return the view page with the '$arra' value where I affect DB:select

```
$arra = array('client'=>$client);


return view('DF.detail', $arr, $arra);
```

Comment: what is `$arr`?

Comment: A value you want to pass to the view?

Comment: I've modified in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the view takes an array of arguments `view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = []))`

So if you want to pass `DF` and `client` to the view, you need both on the same array

```
return view('DF.detail', ['DF' => $DF, 'client' => $client]);
```

Or the same with the same result using `compact`

```
return view('DF.detail', compact('DF', 'client');
```

---

Then on your view (e.g.)

```
<p>{{$DF->id}}: {{$client->name}}</p>
```

Comment: I got an error in view page       : Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:...\resources\views\DF\detail.blade.php)

Comment: is `$client` should be a single result or multiple of results (client**s**)?

Comment: IT SHOULD BE SINGLE : 
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ $client->name}}</h3>   but [name]  got this error ::Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Then, replace `->get` with `->first()` on your query

Comment: THANK YOU THAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM